# CSS Saving Error with Dreamweaver: Solution?

Tags: css, dreamweaver

I'm experiencing an extremely perplexing error that I've been unable to find any posts about online.

I have a CSS file ('main.css') that is linked to my HTML file. Recently, this has started happening:

1) For some reason, upon opening the HTML file, the linked CSS file appears twice.

[image]

2) I go to file -> save all, and the dreamweaver formatting disappears, as though it's an ordinary text file. If I exit and open up the HTML again, the changes haven't saved.

[image]

3) Also when I click file -> save all, a new css file is created in the css directory.

[image]

I honestly haven't the slightest idea what's going on here, and would appreciate any assistance that could be rendered!

Answer (score 0):

Is your Dreamweaver connected to FTP server where the actual website CSS is present online?

Comment: Hey - no, this is all working from a local directory (not a localhost, just from a straight directory - there's no server communication needed).